# Complex unions as return type annotations in Python?

Tags: python, pattern-matching, return-type, python-3.10

I'm writing a basic python function that takes user input, checks if it's valid, and returns `True` if the input is valid and `False` accompanied by an error message of type `str` if not. Here's what my attempt at representing it in code looks like:

```py
def validate(inp: str) -> True | Tuple[False, str]:
  if invalid(inp): return (False, "Brief Error Message")
  return True
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like I can create a return type 'on the fly' as specified above (at least with that syntax), and in order to make my interpreter happy I need to specify the True/False with the more general bool, resulting in a return type that looks like `bool | Tuple[Bool, str]`.

This specific example is at least has pretty easy workarounds, although I can imagine unions getting very messy very fast if I was using something like an enum rather than a bool and my type signature looked like `Color.RED | Tuple[Color.GREEN, str] | Tuple[Color.BLUE, int, set]`, for example.

Is there a way of leveraging the type system/pattern matching to define return types in a similarly striaghtforward manner?

Comment: MyPy gives a useful message: "Invalid type: try using Literal[True] instead?" If you do that it works: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=71487bd056051a12ef778534ba8f430d.

Comment: I would just return `(True, "")` if the input is valid. Or, since your return value will be truthy in either case, just return `None` if valid and raise an exception if not.